# How to Implement Search within WebGrid (Razor/C#)

Tags: c#, .net, sql, razor, webgrid

I'm reading over MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.webgrid(v=VS.99).aspx about the WebGrid - but I can see that there seems to be no search functionality provided with it.

How can we add this functionality to the WebGrid?

Comment: What's the data source for WebGrid? Is it fits into a single page or paging is enabled?

Comment: Definitly paging enabled. The datasource is MS SQL Server 2008 database

Answer (score 1):

Could you have a form that searches the server and just re-renders the WebGrid in a partial view with only the search results showing?